# is it possible to create a Android application that can replace other applications text

Tags: android

I wanted to know if it is possible to create 
a Android application, when it is running (in background) it replaces if text for example:

- "`(smiley)`" => "`:)`"

it should work for all other applications

If yes, then how?

I've tried to create custom symbols via `SoftKeyboard`, but that is not what i want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One app cannot directly change the contents of another app's UI.

An input method editor (IME, a.k.a., "soft keyboard") may be able to help the user create emoticons and the like, but the user has to opt into using it.